# Stata: Adding an interaction term to a regression

Tags: regression, interaction, stata

I'm currently trying to fit a linear regression in Stata as follows: `xi:reg Dependent IV_Rating IV_Size`

I aim to see if the impact (coefficient) of `IV_Rating` on the dependent variable is significantly different for the small size, compared to the large size (both derived from `IV_Size`). I've made two dummies (`0`= false and `1`= true) for `IV_Size` called `Small` and `Large` (medium is excluded). I've ran the following: `xi:reg Dependent IV_Rating IV_Size IV_Rating#Small IV_Rating#Large`

> Error: factor variables may not contain negative values

I found the following fix: I add `c`. (continuous variable) although the `IV_Rating` variable only goes from -3 to +3. `xi:reg Dependent IV_Rating IV_Size c.IV_Rating#Small c.IV_Rating#Large`

The P values for both interactions are not significant, which is as expected (both IVs themselves are still significant). But I also read you can use `##` instead of `#`, and I'm starting to get really confused, among other things. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the coding to positive integers (perhaps using `recode`):

```
x   x2
-3  1
-2  2
-1  3
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Also, you can use factor variable notation directly (instead of `xi`):

```
reg y i.x2##i.z
```

This will include main effects for the two categorical variables as well as their interaction.

Comment: Thank you! That recoding sorted out the error I had indeed. And I now realize what the `##` was meant for. Thank you!